# Unable to close popup box with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am unable to close a popup box with Selenium.  Below is the code I have written, it returns an exception.  Please see the code below.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/webhp#q=home+depot+san+francisco&lrd=0x808f7c5c63124c7b:0x32c19e9988b2aa90,1,")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_wzh"]').click()
# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It take some time to open your popup. So you need to wait for few seconds until the popup opens and close button get visible.

User `Explicitwait` condition until visibility of element like below :

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div>._wzh"))
)
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to click on element, you should use the built-in support.
Following should work.

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept
```

[Docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html?highlight=alert#popup-dialogs)

Comment: Good answer. But i guess the downvote was because the OP is not trying to close a browser alert but a "modal dialogue box" which simulates same.

Comment: @JohnMee - Thanks! I did not looked at the actual page. Based my answer on the question.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the element is present on an `<iframe>` tag; so first you need to switch to iframe and then interact with the element:

```
driver.switch_to.frame driver.find_element_by_css(' #gsr > iframe')
```

then click on the element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_wzh"]').click()
```